# AES 128bit encryption. Inconsistent byte reads from stored SecretKey

Tags: java, aes

I'm trying to set up the following. I have a password to encrypt, I generate a key and store the key to file, I use this stored key to encrypt a string 'password' and it returns 'OePTgm4jy8vbOO8Kf+XTaA==' for example, I later pass this string into a decrypter which loads the stored key from file and converts it back to password in a java class file.

I have this working, but only some of the time. The problem appears to be when I read the key file. When I write the key using:

```
System.out.println("write:" + key.getEncoded().length);
```

I get "write:16"

when I read this again I get either read:16 or read:17 (most usually read:17).

The code I'm using to write the SecretKey is:

```
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128); // 128 default; 192 and 256 also possible
    SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    return key;
```

the to read it:

```
    String hex = new String(readFileToByteArray(file));
    byte[] encoded = new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray();
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
    System.out.println("read:" + key.getEncoded().length);
    return key;
```

When it fails the error is caught here:

```
    byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
    System.out.println(key.getEncoded().length);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    **} catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();**
    }



read:17
17
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 17 bytes
at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
at au.edu.uts.itd.encryption.manager.AESEncrypter.<init>(AESEncrypter.java:21)
at au.edu.uts.itd.encryption.util.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized
at javax.crypto.Cipher.c(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
at au.edu.uts.itd.encryption.manager.AESEncrypter.encrypt(AESEncrypter.java:39)
at au.edu.uts.itd.encryption.util.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:27)
```

So the fact I writing 16 and retrieving 17 bytes is the problem I believe.

Can someone advise on how to ensure the read is 16 bytes as it was written?

Comment: I don't see any code that writes to a file.

Comment: what does readFileToByteArray() do. You should set the encoding for all String actions? Why are you use the BigInteger class....you can just say: yourString.getBytes() or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are tripping over the `BigInteger` to `byte[]` conversion. If the most significant bit of your BigInteger is set, which will happen 50% of the time on average, then the conversion adds an extra zero-byte to the beginning of the byte array. This is because, in Java, the first bit of a byte array that represents a BigInteger is treated as the number's sign bit.

But I don't understand why you are dealing with BigInteger anyway. When reading the file, why are you calling `readFileToByteArray()`, then turning the result into a String, a BigInteger and then back to a byte array ? Why not just code it like this:

```
byte[] encoded = readFileToByteArray(file);
```

?